# my code won't save inputs to a file

Tags: python, saving-data

my code wont save the file

```
#ask for name
name=input("what is your name?")
print("start your quiz " + name + "!")
user=input
class123=('1','2','3')
class123=input("what class are you in 1,2 or 3") 
#get random number
import random
#ask number of questions you want
score=0
count=10
#start while loop
while count != 0:
   num1=random.randint(1,8)
   num2=random.randint(1,8)
   symbol=random.choice(['*','+','-'])
   if symbol=="*":
      user=int(input(str(num1) + "*" + str(num2)))
      count=count-1
      answer=num1 * num2
      if user==answer:
         print("well done your score goes up by 1")
         score=score+1
      else:
         print("this is wrong next question")
   elif symbol=="+":
      user=int(input(str(num1) + "+" + str(num2)))`enter code here`
      count=count-1
      answer=num1 + num2
      if user==answer:
         print("well done your score goes up by 1")
         score=score+1
      else:
         print("this is wrong next question")
   elif symbol=="-":
      user=int(input(str(num1) + "-" + str(num2)))
      count=count-1
      answer=num1 - num2
      if user==answer:
         print("well done your score goes up by 1")
         score=score+1
      else:
         print("this is wrong next question")
#get final score
print(" your score was " + str(score) + " well done ")
#save data into 3 classes

while score == 10 and score >= 0:
    if class123 == '1':
      inFile = open("Class1.txt", 'a')
      inFile.write("\n" + name + ":" + str(score))
      inFile.close()
      score = -1
    elif class123 == '2':
      inFile = open("Class2.txt", 'a')
      inFile.write("\n" + name + ":" + str(score))
      inFile.close()
      score = -1
    elif class123 == '3':
      inFile = open("Class3.txt", 'a')
      inFile.write("\n" + name + ":" + str(score))
      inFile.close()
      score = -1
```

Comment: Sounds terrible, done any debugging?

Comment: If this is your GCSE coursework you're well behind - everyone else cheating on this was here weeks ago.

Comment: Hint: think about what `while score == 10 and score >= 0:` means.

Comment: no the bottom bit and jonrsharpe that's nasty i am improving it because I'm an independent learner

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to work, first off remove or comment out the 'enter code here' part on line 26. It can be done with '#'. The reason is '' is a string and will be interpreted as a string in a place where it shouldn't be.

```
user=int(input(str(num1) + "+" + str(num2))) #enter code here
```

2nd, it's not saved because while never runs, as while score == 10 is not true, so the loop where you write the score never runs.

You can just change it to something like:

```
while score <= 10 and score >= 0:
```

I tested the 2 adjustments I made and, well, your code would run and create the Class?.txt file

Yet as others mention, it's not quite the right structure. Not quite the right usage of stuff. So you may want to improve your code, but here I just gave you a few fixes how to actually get it to run, if you don't mind.